# gen_bridge_support ignores variadic functions

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I'm trying to use a c library in RubyMotion, and in order to call out to functions in the library I need to generate a `bridgesupport` file. RubyMotion is requesting the generation of this file, but I can see that not a single variadic function from the library appears in the `bridgesupport` file. I've tried walking through the source of `gen_bridge_metadata`, but in the end it calls out to a parser in a shared object lib so I can't get much further than that. All I can see is that it's not declaring an `AFunctionDecl` for that function.

Are variadic functions just not supported full stop, or is there some sort of config that I need to apply somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So this appears to be caused by not having all the .h and .a files for the library and it's dependencies together in the same directories. Eg. I had:

```
/vendor/lib1
/vendor/lib2
/vendor/lib3
```

when I should have had

```
/vendor/lib3 (containing all of lib1 + lib2 as well)
```